# Best way for storing 100+ questions and answers

Tags: ios, data-storage

I am designing an exam practice app that will have the following format, requiring the user to rank the answer 1-5 to sections A-E (using a scroll view) for the same question that will be displayed at the top.

Here is an image:

[image]

Each question therefore has 5 parts. I am unsure of what is the best way to store the questions and answers. I read something about plists. Would that be the way to do it? If so, could you recommend any tutorials with images?

Just to clarify, the labels A-E are where the text for the subsections will go and the user will have to rank the appropriateness for each of these.

Thank you!

Comment: Use an sqlite database. 2 tables. One the questions, one the 5 parts that bind to the question id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Few options here:

**1. [Core Data](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html)**

Prepopulate .sqlite file with questions and include with app. Keep track of user's progress and attempts and whatever other stats.

This approach also give your ability to label questions by a topic (or any other criteria) and present questions to user that they need or that they failed most.

**2 Get data from server**

A bit more complicated but offers more benefits. With this approach you would be getting questions in json format.

Benefit of this approach is that you can add any number number of questions and tests without resubmitting your app.

**3. Store as text/plist with app**

Yes, you can also store your questions as text in plist or json format and as app loads populate core data or keep it in memory to display. The latter approach, however, would offer the least amount of benefit and flexibility to the user.

Comment: Thanks. I've had a look at sqlite but that seems more complicated than JSON because SQL is a whole new language and I am inclined to learning the latter as it might help in development of future applications as well. Do you know any good tutorials on firstly creating a json database and secondly integrating it into an app?

Comment: This is a good tutorial on how to preload and import existing data.: http://www.raywenderlich.com/12170/core-data-tutorial-how-to-preloadimport-existing-data-updated  I also have a tool that I used to do it, I'll try to make it more generic and share it on github

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using SQLite. See [Ray Wenderlich's Tutorial on SQLite for iOS](http://www.raywenderlich.com/913/sqlite-tutorial-for-ios-making-our-app)
And there is obviously a not so suitable but easy way and that is using property lists as key and value pairs which i do not recommend.